# how to write jquery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get the value of div and pass the value inside the url using jQuery in **wordpress divi code module**

I am getting undefined error inside the console

this is my jquery code

```
jQuery(".xsub").click(function(){

console.log(jQuery("div#user-region").val());
var xst = document.getElementById('user-region');
console.log(xst.value);
window.location.href ='https://jobplace360.com/hud/hud-listings/?'+xst;
});
```

I am getting inside the url **[object%20HTMLDivElement]** while the new page is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
  var $=jQuery.noConflict();

  $(document).ready(function(){
      // Handler for .ready() called.
      $(".xsub").click(function(){
        console.log($("div#user-region").val());
        var xst = $('#user-region').html();
        console.log(xst);
        window.location.href ='https://jobplace360.com/hud/hud-listings/?'+xst;
      });

    });
```

Comment: not working Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):284)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
(anonymous) @ (index):284
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra  did adding that 1st line fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use innerHtml.

```
var xst = document.getElementById('user-region').innerHtml;
```